# How to use dropzone inside a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, dropzone.js, dropzone

I want to use dropzone inside a form and submit images along with the form submit. So I used as shown below but this way it will accept the image if it drops anywhere in the form. But I want to allow the user only drop their image in "dropClickable" div. How can I achieve that?

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="action" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" novalidate="novalidate" class="dropzone">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-10">
     </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2" id="dropClickable">
        Drop Your File here...!!
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have already try this

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

but this way it will submit images on other path and I want to submit images only with a form with other form data.

Please help me!

Answer (score -2):

You need to do some configuration in order to achieve that

```
autoProcessQueue: false
```

Here are those configurations:

- `autoProcessQueue:` false Dropzone should wait for the user to click a button to upload
- `uploadMultiple:` true Dropzone should upload all files at once (including the form data) not all files individually
- `parallelUploads:` 100 that means that they shouldn't be split up in chunks as well
- `maxFiles: 100` this is to make sure that the user doesn't drop more files than allowed in one request.

Have a look at below code

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  uploadMultiple: true,
  parallelUploads: 100,
  maxFiles: 100,
  init: function() {
   // Do your update and process stuff
  }
```